# ReadP recursive parsing

Tags: parsing, haskell, recursion

In a [wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/ParseExps) about parsing a string like `"(a*b+c^d)"` into a tree using [ReadP](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html), there is the following piece of code:

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP

brackets p = do char '('
                r <- p
                char ')'
                return r

data Operator = Add | Mul | Exp deriving Show
operators = [(Add,'+'),(Mul,'*'),(Exp,'^')]

data Tree = Branch Operator Tree Tree | Leaf String deriving Show

leaf = do s <- many1 (choice (map char ['a'..'z']))
          return (Leaf s)

tree = foldr (\(op,name) p ->
               let this = p +++ (p +++ brackets tree
                        >>= (\a -> char name
                        >>= (\_ -> this
                        >>= (\b -> return (Branch op a b)))))
                in this)
             (leaf +++ brackets tree)
             operators
```

What I cannot get is the way the recursion on `this` works here (I've desugared `do` hoping it would help me understand it, to no avail). Can someone please explain how `this` within the `do`-block gets evaluated (since it looks like infinite recursion to me, which it obviously isn't)?

Comment: As an aside, `brackets` looks a bit more concise as `brackets p = char '(' *> p <* char ')'` and `leaf = Leaf <$> many1 (choice (map char ['a'..'z']))`.

Comment: In a sense, every recursion is infinite. E.g. `let x = (1, 2 + fst x) in snd x` looks as if it loops forever but does not. Above, `this` is  a function in disguise, and `>>=` is passing a different argument to it every time we recurse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the definition of `this` (I find it easier to work with the `do` notation):

```
let this = p +++ do a <- p +++ brackets tree
                    char name
                    b <- this
                    return (Branch op a b)
 in this
```

So here, the only occurrence of `this` in the right hand side, is inside the second argument to the `+++` operation, which is:

```
do a <- p +++ brackets tree
   char name
   b <- this
   return (Branch op a b)
```

As you can see, in this expression, `this` appears after some other operations, namely `a <- p +++ brackets tree` and `char name`. This means that these other operations will be tried first before `this`. If one of them fails, then none of the subsequent operations will be tried. So for example, if `a <- p +++ brackets tree` succeeds, but then the input stream does not contain a character equal to value reference by `name`, `char name` will fail and the `b <- this` line will not be attempted at all. So this means that it is not necessary that `this` will recursively invoke itself *unconditionally*.

Comment: It is even shorter and simpler with applicative notation: `this = p +++ (Branch op <$> (p +++ brackets tree <* char name) <*> this)`

Comment: @user2407038 Yes indeed. I merely copied the code from wikibooks to explain how it works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate way of seeing the definition of `tree`:

```
t0 = leaf +++ brackets tree
t1 = do a <- t0 +++ (t0 +++ brackets tree)
        char '+'
        b <- t1
        return (Branch Add a b)
t2 = do a <- t1 +++ (t1 +++ brackets tree)
        char '*'
        b <- t2
        return (Branch Mul a b)
t3 = do a <- t2 +++ (t2 +++ brackets tree)
        char '^'
        b <- t3
        return (Branch Exp a b)
tree = t3
```

Note the is a circular dependency in the definition of tree: `tree` -> `t3` -> `t2` -> `t1` -> `t0` -> `tree`. The definition of `t0` "ties the knot" since
it refers to `brackets tree`.

Each level adds the ability to parse a new operator: `t0` parses just
leaf nodes and brackets, `t1` adds addition on top of `t0`, `t2`
adds multiplication on top of `t1`, etc.

(Edit: Actually, since this is a right fold the operators are effectively added in the reverse order - ie. `t1` adds exponentiation and `t3` adds addition.)

This makes the final parser `tree` right associative, i.e. `a+b+c` is parsed as `a + (b + c)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I accepted the other one, your hint that this is an instance of "tying the knot" was really helpful too.